# How to Style AvalonEdit ScrollBars

Tags: wpf, avalonedit

I'm trying to change the thumb color of the scrollbars in AvalonEdit. I've tried a number of approaches:

Style the ScrollViewer - lots of examples but I can't get most of them to compile and when I do they don't work.

Use FindTemplate and change thumb colors at runtime. Works in many but not all cases.

All I want is to change the thumb color. Come'on WPF, throw me a bone.

Please someone put me out of my misery and show me how.

---

Follow up:

I was able to get most of what I wanted by changing the default thumb style:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type Thumb}"
           TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.1" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

However, if I try to add a control template to this style, it has no effect. Every time I think I understand WPF styling, something happens to convince me I know nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this page: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742173(v=vs.110).aspx)

you can do something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}"  x:Key="ScrollBarThumb">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Border CornerRadius="2"
                            Background="Black"
                            BorderBrush="Red"
                            BorderThickness="1" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

<Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition MaxHeight="18" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*" />
                            <RowDefinition MaxHeight="18" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border Grid.RowSpan="3" />
                        <RepeatButton Grid.Row="0"
                                      Command="ScrollBar.LineUpCommand"
                                      Content="M 0 4 L 8 4 L 4 0 Z" />
                        <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="1" IsDirectionReversed="true">
                            <Track.Thumb>
                                <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}" Margin="1,0,1,0"/>
                            </Track.Thumb>
                        </Track>
                        <RepeatButton Grid.Row="3"
                                      Command="ScrollBar.LineDownCommand"
                                      Content="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Interesting, so to modify the thumb template you have to modify the scrollbar template. I would not have expected that.